# List all file Name of a directory to Text File

Tags: python, python-3.3

I've my code like this, but the problem is it only gives the last file name in output.txt instead of all 30 file names.

```
import os
path="path I wanted"  
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for filename in dirList:
    print (filename)
    f = open("output1.txt", "w")
    f.write(filename) 
    f.close()
```

Comment: Hint: You're overwriting the file. _sssh_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'w' flag to 'open' truncates the file on every iteration through the loop. If the file already exists, use the 'a' flag instead. For more info, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Although this _may_ work for the example, are you suggesting that the OP should be opening the file and creating a new file object on each iteration? Not very efficient nor pretty. Not to mention the `seek` operations needed to append data to the file on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You're *overwriting* the file in each loop iteration. Open it before everything else:

```
import os
path="path I wanted"  
dirList=os.listdir(path)
with open("output1.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in dirList:
        print (filename)
        f.write(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, with a couple of extra improvements:

```
import os

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines([f for f in os.listdir(path)])
```

You are over-writing the file in each iteration. Therefore, we `open` it before writing all the lines to the `file`.

Comment: +1 When I have a son I hope he likes programming! ;)

Comment: @PauloBu Thank you! Just trying to get myself out there and share my abilities!

Comment: @PauloBu your daughters might also enjoy programming, if you give them a chance!

Comment: @GilesGardam Of course! English is not my primary language but what I really meant was "when I have a child" :-)